# RL: Self-Play with On-Policy and Off-Policy

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I try to implement self play with PPO.
Suppose we have a game with 2 agents. We control one player on each side and get information like observation and reward after each step. As far as I know, you can use the information of the right and left player to generate training data and to optimize the model. But that is only possible for off-policy, isn't it?
Because with on-policy e.g. PPO, you expect that the training data to be generated by the current network version and that is usually not the case during self play?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, this is also the same reason why you can use experience-replay (Replay BUffers) only for off-policy methods like Q-learning. Using sample steps that were not generated by the current policy violates the mathematical assumptions behind the gradients that are being backpropagated.